How to fix ZUUL exception forwarding error
i am using a springboot microservice project. i have gateway, discovery an some more projects.
i deployed this in the aws cloud front container.
After the deployment, i am facing some zuul exception randomly. its not happening all the time, but randomly happening once i call the api for fist time. and on the second time its working fine. and i am only getting the error in the gateway.
We are using the dependencey:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


error:
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   2024-04-12 14:28:30.955 WARN 2628 --- [nio-8122-exec-1] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter : Error during filtering
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.handleException(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:261) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:241) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:4.0.1]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:4.0.1]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at com.myProject.gateway.jwtconfig.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:127) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.8.jar!/:5.4.8]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:97) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.11.jar!/:2.4.11]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar!/:5.3.10]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar!/:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186) ~[na:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[na:na]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:422) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:341) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:236) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   ... 98 common frames omitted
2024-04-12T19:58:30.957+05:30   


gateway application.yml is look like :
server:  
  port: 8122
  tomcat:
    connection-timeout: 180000

management:
  endpoint:
    serviceregistry:
      enabled: true
    restart:
      enabled: true
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
    health:
      enabled: true

zuul:
  ignored-headers: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  host:
    socket-timeout-millis: 500000
    connect-timeout-millis: 500000
  routes:
    serviceOne: 
      url: <deployedURL>:8123 
    serviceTwo:
      url: <deployedURL>:8124
    serviceThree:
      url: <deployedURL>:8125  
    serviceFour:
      url: <deployedURL>:8126
    serviceFive:
      url: <deployedURL>:8127
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      eager-load: true
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true  
  ReadTimeout: 600000
  ConnectTimeout: 1000000
  MaxAutoRetries: 1
  MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 1

eureka:
  instance:
    appname: discovery-service
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: <deployedURL>:8121/eureka/
    registerWithEureka: false

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 1000000
          semaphore:
            maxConcurrentRequests: 2000
        timeout:
          enabled: false

tried changing the zuul versions to 2.2.10.RELEASE and 2.2.8.RELEASE which didnt worked.
also tried with changing some of the timeout, which also didn't worked out.
